# Изменение значений в App.config во время работы программы

Tags: c#, .net, config

Подскажите, можно ли Setting, которая имеет Scope "Application" менять в app.config во время работы программы и сохранять?

Вот эта штука работает для user scope:

```
 Settings.Default.ReplaceConfig = writer.ToString();
        Settings.Default.Save();
```

Но не работает для Application, ругаясь, что свойство Read-only.
Можно ли это обойти?

Меня интересует изменение и сохранение настроек в такой секции:

```
    <applicationSettings>
    <Proga.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="Str" serializeAs="String">
            <value>Test</value>
        </setting>
    </Proga.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

За отсутствие прав у пользователя к каталогу с программой можно не беспокоится.

Можно считать, что юзер Админ.

Answer (score 3):

Это возможно. Например, пусть имеется конфигурационный файл следующего вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="test" value="123"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Код для изменения значений в конфиге (необходимо добавить референс на `System.Configuration`):

```
// открываем application scope-конфиг
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

Console.WriteLine("appSettings[test] = {0}",
    config.AppSettings.Settings["test"].Value); // выводит 123

config.AppSettings.Settings["test"].Value = "456";
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

Console.WriteLine("appSettings[test] = {0}",
    config.AppSettings.Settings["test"].Value); // выводит 456
```

После выполнения кода в файле будет сохранено новое значение:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="test" value="456" />
</appSettings>
```

---

**Вариант с applicationSettings**

В этом случае данные также можно записать. Код для обработки будет выглядеть чуть сложнее:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var section = (ClientSettingsSection) config
    .GetSectionGroup("applicationSettings")
    .Sections["Proga.Properties.Settings"];

// получаем значение параметра Str
var oldSetting = section.Settings.Get("Str");
string oldValue = oldSetting.Value.ValueXml.InnerText;
Console.WriteLine("Str = {0}", oldValue); // Test

// вручную создаем параметр с новым значением
var newSetting = new SettingElement("Str", SettingsSerializeAs.String);
newSetting.Value = new SettingValueElement();
newSetting.Value.ValueXml = new XmlDocument().CreateElement("value");
newSetting.Value.ValueXml.InnerText = "4567";

// заменяем старый параметр на новый
section.Settings.Remove(oldSetting);
section.Settings.Add(newSetting);

config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("Proga.Properties.Settings");
```

Comment: Я немного обоновил вопрос. Данный метод прокатит для такой секции?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Да, тоже можно сохранить. Но код получается уж очень костыльный, может, кто-то предложит способ лучше...

Comment: @kmv: С User Settings такое прокатит, а с ApplicationSettings скорее всего нет, т. к. программа обычно лежит в каталоге под Program Files, и доступ на запись есть лишь у администратора (а запущена программа с правами юзера).

Comment: @VladD в этом случае, конечно, будет ошибка. Если же программа лежит в произвольном каталоге с нужными разрешениями, то работать будет.

Answer (score 0):

Параметры с областью действия приложения доступны только для чтения. Их можно изменить только во время разработки или путем изменения CONFIG-файла между сеансами приложения. Параметры, имеющие область действия пользователя, однако, можно записывать во время выполнения так же, как значение любого свойства. Новое значение сохраняется в течение всего сеанса приложения. Для сохранения изменений параметров между сеансами приложения вызовите метод Save